Data Cleaning in Odoo (notifications, website-visitors...)
I have noticed that my Odoo16-Database size has drastically grown over the last months.
And i want to clear all the obsolete records of all involved models (notifications, web visitors...).
The Odoo - Data Cleaning App enables to perform cleaning actions but not on all models.
I have started with Web-visitors cleaning by writing this ir-cron Task to delete records older than 15 days:
env['website.visitor'].search([('create_date','<',datetime.datetime.now()-datetime.timedelta(days=15))]).unlink()


Have you such a way to clean old notifications (messages and mails) in odoo without triggering bugs or unexpected behaviors? (something better than MARK ALL AS READ as suggested here: https://www.odoo.com/fr_FR/forum/aide-1/bulk-clear-notifications-dismiss-all-conversations-as-read-173110). Is it safe to achieve it this way ?

env['mail.notification'].search([('notification_status','!=','ready'),('mail_message_id.date','<',datetime.datetime.now()-datetime.timedelta(days=360))]).unlink()


How about the records of the 'mail.message'-model linked to the'mail.notification'-model via a Many2One field ?

Do you know what other models could be cleaned in odoo to keep DB as light as possibe ?





That question is very hard to answer. It is extremely dependent on what is mainly done with the system. For example: if a lot of important communication takes place in the system, it makes little sense to delete messages. In the end, the person who knows what the system is used for has to decide and set up or programme the corresponding routines. Your approach already seems appropriate to me. As for notifications: You should set the subtypes  (mail.message.subtype) differently than in the standard configuration in order to trigger fewer notifications.

And deleting messages (mail.message) should also delete related notfications.
